# preg_replace with names including hyphen for double barrelled surnames

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I allow users to enter their surname using hyphens (eg `Jones-Smith`) but remove all other non-alphanumerics?

Currently I'm using this:

```
 $_POST['Surname'] = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $_POST['Surname']);
```

Which is perfect except it removes hyphens. Any advice?

Comment: There is only 1 sure-fire way to accurately match names; a single `name` field with `.*` for verification : http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ - with what you've got there you're already excluding all  the *O'Malleys*  of the world... and without the Unicode flag, probably most of South East Asia.

Comment: Why not let a user enter anything, and then validate upon submit with a more straight-forward regex like `'~\A\w+(?:[\'-]\w+)*\z~u'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep hyphens, simply add them to your negated character set like this:

```
$_POST['Surname'] = preg_replace("/[^ \w\-]+/", "", $_POST['Surname']);
```

Comment: Escaping the hyphen is not necessary if it is the first or last character in the class.